# What kind of software or animation tool does google use to make its explainer (how it works) videos?

Tags: animation, video, whiteboard

Have you ever watched any of google's explanatory whiteboard videos, like "inside search"? How do they make these kind of catchy, impressive animation videos? Do they use their own tool? I've heard online tools like powtoon, animaker etc., those videos dont have that simple impressing quality. Does anyone know about how google makes these kind of animation videos??

https://youtu.be/TYHCeUfoAnw

Answer (score -1):

For those animations you need a specialized software application for animators. The video you provided is a Hand Drawn Animation not a Whiteboard Animation (powtoon,animaker). That's why the quality is "impressing". For the first one you can try this **free** tool: http://animationpaper.com/